# Merging two arrays by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

let's say I have two numpy arrays `a = (n x m)` and `b = (z x m)` where columns m are some common identifier.

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1]])
b = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

is there a numpy-ish way to get `c = (n x z)` where `c_ij = 1 if (any element in (row i of a AND row j of b) is equal to 1) else 0` without loops, so in this case

```
c = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Can you post a loop based version of this that returns the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could look at it as a matrix multiplication:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> b = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> (a.dot(b.T) > 0).astype(int)
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

The downside is that this approach does a lot more work than it needs to, because it does the whole multiplication.  If performance is really critical (and it's critical a lot less often than people think it's critical) you could write a bit of cython or use numba to get the short-circuiting behaviour back with C-like speed.  One of the local numpy wizards will probably think of something clever, though. :^)

Comment: If numpy is compiled with a decent BLAS this will be very difficult to beat with pure numpy as numpy's `any` function (IIRC) does not break on the first true and instead zips through the entire array. You might be able to do a bit better if you call `SGEMM` directly through scipy.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said without loops, but this works:

```
np.array([[np.any(x&y) for x in a] for y in b],dtype=int).T
```